# Dynamic linq query is not working with numeric value

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic-linq

This is my code:

```
// Taken from combobox selection.
string columnName = cboCrudSearchColumn.Text.ToString(); 

// Taken from textbox selection.
string searchValue = txtCrudSearch.Text.ToString(); 

dgvLoadTable.DataSource = EntityName
    .TableName
    .Where(columnName + " = @0", searchValue )
    .ToList();
```

Now, this works fine when searchValue is a string (ex: ABC), but when it is a numeric value (ex: 30) it gives the following exception: Operator '=' incompatible with operand types 'Decimal' and 'String. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to include a parameter. Note paratmeters can't start with numeric or symbolic characters (much like variables).

Comment: With the code in your example searchValue is always a string.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, then why does it throw the exception? It also doesn't work with DateTime.

Comment: @Paradox probably since the column it is comparing with is not a string. Example `Amount = 'Hej'` where Amount is of type decimal would not work very well.

Answer (score 0):

You use parametrized query and pass as parameter string value, so this parameter have type string and you get error with operand types.

for solving just pass decimal value, like

```
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = EntityName
    .TableName
    .Where(columnName + " = @0", int.Parse(searchValue) )
    .ToList();
```